# Implementation of a stack using a circular double linked list

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, stack, doubly-linked-list

I want to implement a stack using a circular double linked list.

```
typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next,*prev;
}cdllnode;
```

```
cdllnode* createcdllnode(int data){
    cdllnode* newnode=(cdllnode*)malloc(sizeof(cdllnode));
    newnode->data=data;
    newnode->next=NULL;
    newnode->prev=NULL;
    return newnode;
}
```

```
cdllnode* push(cdllnode *head,cdllnode *tos,int data){
    cdllnode *newnode = createcdllnode(data);
    if(head==NULL){
        head=newnode;
        tos=head;
    }
    else{
        tos->next=newnode;
        newnode->prev=tos;
        tos=newnode;
        tos->next=head;
        head->prev=tos;
    }
    return head;

}
```

```
int pop(cdllnode *head,cdllnode *tos){
    if(head==NULL){
        printf("Empty Stack!\n");
        return INT_MIN;
    }

    int temp= tos->data;
    tos=tos->prev;
    tos->next=head;
    head->prev=tos;
    return temp;
}
```

```
void printstack(cdllnode *head,cdllnode *tos){
        if(head==NULL){
        printf("Empty Stack!\n");
        return ;
    }

    cdllnode *p=tos;
    do{
      printf("%d\n",p->data);
      p=p->prev;
    }while(p!=tos);
}
```

I'm able to push the first element but if I try inserting any element after that,I'm getting a segmentation fault.
Same is the case with the pop and printstack function.

**EDIT**

I corrected my code. It was unnecessary to use two pointers to access the list.This code works perfectly fine.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<limits.h>

typedef struct dnode{
    int data;
    struct dnode *next,*prev;
}cdllnode;

cdllnode* createcdllnode(int data){
    cdllnode* newnode=(cdllnode*)malloc(sizeof(cdllnode));
    newnode->data=data;
    newnode->next=NULL;
    newnode->prev=NULL;
    return newnode;
}

cdllnode* push(cdllnode *head,int data){
    cdllnode *newnode = createcdllnode(data);
    if(head==NULL){
        head=newnode;
    }
    else if(head->next==NULL){
        head->next=newnode;
        newnode->prev=head;
        newnode->next=head;
        head->prev=newnode;
    }
    else{
        cdllnode *p = head;
        p=head->prev;
        p->next=newnode;
        newnode->prev=p;
        newnode->next=head;
        head->prev=newnode;

    }
    return head;

}

cdllnode* pop(cdllnode *head,int *temp){
    if(head==NULL){
        printf("Empty Stack!\n");
        *temp= INT_MIN;
        return head;
    }

    if(head->next==head){
        *temp=head->data;
        head=NULL;
    }
    else{
        cdllnode *p=head->prev;
        *temp= p->data;
        p=p->prev;
        p->next=head;
        head->prev=p;
    }
    return head;
}

void printstack(cdllnode *head){
        if(head==NULL){
        printf("Empty Stack!\n");
        return ;
    }
    cdllnode *p=head;
    do{
        if(p->next== head){
            printf("%d\n",p->data);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d->",p->data);
        }

        p=p->next;
    }while(p!=head);
}

int main(){
    cdllnode *head=NULL;
    int choice,ele;

    do{
        printf("1.PUSH\t2.POP\t3.PRINT\t4.EXIT\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice){
        case 1 :{
            printf("Enter an element.\n");
            scanf("%d",&ele);
            head=push(head,ele);
            printf("Element Added!\n");
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            head=pop(head,&ele);
            if(ele!= INT_MIN){
                printf("Popped %d from the stack.\n",ele);
                break;
            }
        }
        case 3:{
            printstack(head);
            break;
        }
        case 4:{
            break;
        }
        default : {
            choice=4;
            break;
        }
    }
}while(choice!=4);
}
```

Comment: Try running your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory, it will tell you where.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including your code that calls the functions. What is the arguments `tos` for?

Comment: You don't show how you push the values, but you pass both the head and the tail ("tos"). You return the head, but the changes you make to the tail are only local and are not visible when the function returns. Create a structure for the whole list that maintains your head and tail and pass that to the functions.

Comment: Why do you want to use a circular list?

Comment: Because that is what the question was.